# Chernoff Bound - Delta variable?

Tags: probability-theory

I am learning Chernoff Bounds and am confused what the delta variable stands for and how it is determined. So far i have not been able to find a source that describes it.

The example i am looking is the example in the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chernoff_bound) page.

In some other examples, i see values being set for delta but i am not sure how to determine this value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With Chernoff bounds, you have some free parameter, like $\delta$, that basically parameterize a family of bounds for a particular value. I don't know if it has a straightforward interpretation, but, since each $\delta$ is associated with a valid upper bound, what people usually do is choose the $\delta$ that provides the *least upper bound*, thus giving the tightest possible chernoff bound.